# "Access token is invalid" error message

Tags: php, google-api, google-sheets

I use the lib https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client
but I get a problem:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Spreadsheet\UnauthorizedException' with message '**Access token is invalid**'
```

I don't now if my generation API access token is good... I did the third steps of this article:
http://konstantinshkut.com/blog/2014/11/01/how_to_get_data_from_google_spreadsheet_in_yii_php_application

But I don't know what doing next...
I just need a simple valid access token to using https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client

I'm not sure if "Create Client ID" should be "API key" or "ID Oauth 2.0" or other... I don't know if the JSON key, or P12 key is necessary, and if it is, I don't know how can I use it with the lib.